# Redis search for matching keys that equal a value

Tags: caching, redis, key-value

OK, in REDIS if i simply want to set up keys = a channel name
and value = either paid or free...

so eventually ill have a list 100s, 1000s, etc etc of keys and values where
the key's value will either be paid or free.

```
     channelName, paid or free
```

so,then i want to come and search
and ask the db give me all the channels whose value = free

whats the best way/efficent way to set this up?

i basically want to query and return a list of all the keys that equal a certain value in a list or dict...

Comment: I should probably use free and paid as the keys and store the channels in some kinda way...hash, set hmmm investigating

Comment: You don't set this up. Redis a key-value store and designed specifically to retrieve the value associated with a certain key. If you want to be able to query on multiple fields, you'll need a different data structure, such as a relational or indexed document database.

Comment: my researching is coming to that...hammer & screw... i want something lightweight for this and hosted/remote got any suggestions

Comment: This is going to be almost completely opinion-based and still largely dependent on the particulars of your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sorted sets](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set), and the member value to be 0 (free) or 1 (paid).

In a single key, you can store the members of the sorted set, and each member is given a decimal value. Abstracting the `free` and `paid` to be `0` and `1` values, you can add members (i.e. in your case, channels) to the set, and later query those.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD mychannels 0 1stchannel 1 2ndchannel 1 3rdchannel 0 4thchannel
(integer) 4
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE mychannels 0 0 /* Querying free channels */
1) "1stchannel"
2) "4thchannel"
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE mychannels 1 1 /* Querying paid channels */
1) "2ndchannel"
2) "3rdchannel"
```

Comment: thanks!! i had come to the understanding of sorted sets and now you just gave me an excellent example to expand upon